# Relay circuit for DC LED strips switch

Tags: switches, relay, esp32, load, latching-relay

Is this schematic OK for 24 V UVC light control via 5 VDC relay?

[image: Schematic]

Comment: What's UVC? Ultra violet-C?

Comment: If you want the LED to light when the relay is activated, it should be in parallel with the relay coil, not between the transistor collector and Ground.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, the relay can handle the input voltage by a factor of 10x

Usually the flyback diode is drawn across the terminals.

You may want to use a FET instead of a BJT to avoid the voltage drop of the BJT which will make it harder for the coil to turn on, but this may not be nessacary since it says it can operate at 75% of the 'pull in voltage' which I assume to mean voltage across the coil. A BJT will give you 86% of the pull in voltage.